# textvariables inadvertently tied together in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Writing a form to handle display/entry of inventory.
The code below has been paired down to next to nothing.  The problem is that I have two, 1 char STR variables that are somehow getting bound together and I can not figure out how or why.

The two vars pull the first and second digits of an INT (after conversion to STR).  If the first and second digits of the INT are the same then the two STR vars become linked - a change to one reflects in the other.  If the two digits are different then the two STR vars are not linked.  I am pretty sure I am doing something stupid but I don't see it.  I have tried renaming vars, initializing, splitting code, eliminating everything down to the bare bones and yet the issue remains.  Anyone want to tell me what stupid thing I am doing?

```
from tkinter import *

class company_frame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self["height"] = 40
        self["width"] = 1300
        self["relief"] = RAISED
        self["bd"] = 8
        self["bg"] = "#dfdfdf"

def inv_form():
    inv = [22001,"6' CAT6 Patch Cable, Blue",2.50,6.00,"02/01/2020","THD",1,1]
    cf = company_frame(root)
    cf.grid(row=0, column=2)

    class_id = StringVar()
    subclass_id = StringVar()
    item_id = StringVar()

    class_id =  str(inv[2])[0]
    subclass_id = str(inv[0])[1]
    item_id = str(inv[0])[2:5]

    # ENTRY SECTION
    class_e = Entry(cf, textvariable=class_id)
    class_e.delete(0, END)
    class_e.insert(0, class_id)
    class_e.config(width=1)

    subclass_e = Entry(cf, textvariable=subclass_id)
    subclass_e.delete(0, END)
    subclass_e.insert(0, subclass_id)
    subclass_e.config(width=1)

    item_e = Entry(cf, textvariable=item_id)
    item_e.delete(0, END)
    item_e.insert(0, item_id)
    item_e.config(width=3)

    #item num
    class_e.grid(row=3, column=1)
    subclass_e.grid(row=3, column=3)
    item_e.grid(row=3, column=5)
    return

root = Tk()
root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
inv_form()
root.mainloop()
'''

Running python 3 on Ubuntu, tkinter is 8.6.
Any light is greatly appreciated.
```

Comment: I apologize, I don't follow.  The StringVars are local but so is the tkinter frame and the dereference of the variables.  The issue is not that the variables change when in a different part of the program but if you run the program, changing the second digit changes the first digit in the frame.  Two local variables not assigned to each other should not do that should they?

Comment: My apologies, my comment was incorrect. I didn't look closely enough at your question. The use of local variables is indeed incorrect, but it's not the root cause of the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't using the `StringVar` instances with the entry widgets. You're setting the `textvariable` attributes to strings, not `StringVar`s. In this specific case, the first two variables are set to the string '"2"' so tkinter thinks they are the same variable. The third is being set to the string `"001"`, so tkinter considers it a separate variable.

This is because you create the instances of `StringVar` and then immediately re-use the same variable name to fetch the value (which is an empty string since you haven't set it to anything else).

You need to remove these three lines which are causing your references to the `StringVar` instances to be forgotten:

```
class_id =  str(inv[2])[0]
subclass_id = str(inv[0])[1]
item_id = str(inv[0])[2:5]
```

You also can remove the following lines of code where you are explicitly inserting something into the entry widgets.

```
class_e.delete(0, END)
class_e.insert(0, class_id)
...
subclass_e.delete(0, END)
subclass_e.insert(0, subclass_id)
...
item_e.delete(0, END)
item_e.insert(0, item_id)
```

... and then add these three lines to initialize the entry widgets:

```
class_id.set(str(inv[2])[0])
subclass_id.set(str(inv[0])[1])
item_id.set(str(inv[0])[2:5])
```

Though, you can combine the creation of the variable and the setting of the default value into a single statement:

```
class_id = StringVar(value=str(inv[2])[0])
subclass_id = StringVar(value=str(inv[0])[1])
item_id = StringVar(value=str(inv[0])[2:5])
```

---

Another problem that isn't the immediate cause of the problem is that you're using local variables for the instances of `StringVar`. When you do that, the variables will get garbage-collected and you won't be able to use then outside of the function. In that case, the use of `StringVar` is pointless.

If you expect to be able to get the values from the widgets in another function you must save a reference to either the widgets themselves or the `StringVar`s

Comment: Bryan - if tkinter thinks they are all the same variable then why does it not also change the item_id?  The relationship issue appears to be limited to class_id and subclass_id.  I am truly baffled by this and trying to understand the issue.  Why would delete the insertions of class_e/subclass_e/item_e, they are not empty and not trivial.

Comment: @AKGlenn: I apologize. I was a bit sloppy in writing the opening paragraph. I've reworded it to be more accurate. The first two `textvariable` options were set to the string `"2"`, so tkinter thinks they are the same variable. The third had a different value so it wasn't linked to the first two.

Comment: Bryan - thank you.  You are right, setting the vars to StringVars, assigning the values and removing the DELETE/INSERTs worked.  Got a question.  Why would tkinter think that the string '2' in both vars of my original version was the same string.  I guess my real question is when would that be an acceptable approach by tkinter?  I suspect the answer to that is a larger programming question so if pointing me elsewhere is appropriate please do.  Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: @AKGlenn "Got a question. Why would tkinter think that the string '2' in both vars of my original version was the same string" - Because tkinter is built on top of a tcl/tk interepreter. The argument that is passed to the tcl/tk interepter is expected to be the name of a variable. So, tcl sees "2" as the name of the first variable, and "2" as the name of the second variable, so they are the same variable (tcl variables can literally be just about anything - numbers, strings, empty strings, etc).

Comment: @AKGlenn: _" I guess my real question is when would that be an acceptable approach by tkinter?"_ - I'm not sure how to answer that. From the perspective of someone using tkinter, the answer is probably "never". It's not ever acceptable to use an integer or a plain string as the value of a `textvariable` option.  The tkinter developers probably should have made that a strict requirement, but they didn't for some unknown reason.